# Cast to youtube chromecast receiver from other android app

Tags: android, youtube, chromecast

I'm adding chromecast support to the app Narwhal TV for reddit https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=org.elsewhat.reddit&hl=en

As it aggregates youtube videos popular on reddit, I want to reuse the youtube chromecast receiver app.

I've made some progress already: I'm able to connect to the chromecast device and start the youtube app. 
However, I am not able to start the playback of a video.  Most of this progress is due to the castv2-youtube project https://github.com/xat/castv2-youtube

Start the youtube application

```
private String CHROMECAST_APP_ID="233637DE";
    Cast.CastApi.launchApplication(mApiClient, CHROMECAST_APP_ID, false)
```

Define the youtube channel

```
    class YoutubeChannel implements Cast.MessageReceivedCallback {
      public String getNamespace() {
        return "urn:x-cast:com.google.youtube.mdx";
      }

      @Override
      public void onMessageReceived(CastDevice castDevice, String namespace,
            String message) {
        Log.d("RedditTV", "onMessageReceived: " + message);
      }
    }
```

Listen to both the media and youtube channels

```
Cast.CastApi.setMessageReceivedCallbacks(mApiClient,
                                 mRemoteMediaPlayer.getNamespace(), mRemoteMediaPlayer);

                        Cast.CastApi.setMessageReceivedCallbacks(mApiClient,
                                youtubeChannel.getNamespace(),
                                youtubeChannel);
```

Send message to start the video

```
String message = String.format(locale,"{\"type\":\"flingVideo\", \"data\":{\"videoId\":\""+redditPost.getYoutubeId()+"\" ,\"currentTime\":%.2f}}",time) ;
        Log.w("RedditTV", "Chromecast message to "+ youtubeChannel.getNamespace() + " :"+message);
          try {
                Cast.CastApi.sendMessage(mApiClient, youtubeChannel.getNamespace(), message)
                .setResultCallback(
                  new ResultCallback<Status>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onResult(Status result) {

                      if (!result.isSuccess()) {
                        Log.e("RedditTV", "Sending message failed");
                      }
                    }
                  });
              } catch (Exception e) {
                Log.e("RedditTV", "Exception while sending message", e);
              }
```

The output of shows the actual message sent (I've also tried to set currentTime as 0)

```
Chromecast message to urn:x-cast:com.google.youtube.mdx :{"type":"flingVideo", "data":{"videoId":"4Bn2SEHsyNY" ,"currentTime":1420065958051.00}}
```

The message is sent successfully, but nothing happens on the chromecast side.

I don't have any good way of debugging it either.

Comment: Did you ever get this to work fully?

Comment: Unfortunately no @OliverBudiardjo  . Ended up with my own receiver (code in https://github.com/elsewhat/reddittv-android/tree/Rename-redditv)